# implicit std::pair construction in variadic template construction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates

I have a `constexpr` key-value map that roughly has this definition:

```
// map with `pos` remaining entries
template<typename K, typename V, size_t pos>
class Map {
public:
    template<class Head, class... Tail>
    constexpr Map(Head head, Tail... tail)
        :
        value{head},
        tail{tail...} {}

    Element<K, V> value;
    const Map<K, V, pos - 1> tail;

    // members etc
};

// map end element.
template<typename K, typename V>
class Map<K, V, 0> {
public:
    constexpr Map() {}

    // end element specifics.
};
```

To initialize a key-value map at compile time, I have a utility function that forwards the elements:

```
template<typename K, typename V, typename... Entries>
constexpr Map<K, V, sizeof...(Entries)> create_const_map(Entries&&... entry) {
    return Map<K, V, sizeof...(entry)>(Entry<K, V>{std::forward<Entries>(entry)}...);
}
```

The `Element` is defined as:

```
template<class K, class V>
class Entry {
public:
    constexpr Entry(const K &key, const V &value)
        :
        key{key},
        value{value} {}

    constexpr Entry(std::pair<K, V> pair)
        :
        key{pair.first},
        value{pair.second} {}

    const K key;
    const V value;
};
```

To actually create a map, I can use `std::make_pair` successfully:

```
constexpr auto cmap = create_const_map<int, int>(
    std::make_pair(0, 0),
    std::make_pair(13, 37),
    std::make_pair(42, 9001)
);
```

What I want now is to eliminate the calls to `std::make_pair` and use braces instead:

```
constexpr auto cmap = create_const_map<int, int>(
    {0, 0},
    {13, 37},
    {42, 9001}
);
```

But this leads to compilation failure as the `{}` are not deduced as construction for pairs:

```
/home/jj/devel/openage/libopenage/datastructure/tests.cpp:191:24: error: no matching function for call to 'create_const_map'
        constexpr auto cmap = create_const_map<int, int>(
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/jj/devel/openage/libopenage/datastructure/constexpr_map.h:286:46: note: candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 3 were provided
constexpr Map<K, V, sizeof...(Entries)> create_const_map(Entries&&... entry) {
                                        ^
```

What can I do so that the `{a, b}` can be used instead of `std::make_pair(a, b)`?

Comment: Instead of a parameter pack of `Entries`, take an `initializer_list` of a new template parameter `E`.

Comment: Are `create_map` and `create_const_map` the same function?

Comment: @DanielJour yes they are, i corrected the typo.

Comment: Can't experiment to better understand without knowing what Map is. I know what std::map is, but not Map.

Comment: @mattnewport unfortunately he has to pass the size as a template argument, but for initializer_list the size is not known as a constant expression passable as template argument. The consequence would be, perhaps to eliminate this size argument.. what is it used for?

Comment: the size argument the counter for the recursive template, each element entry instances a new `Map`, when all elements were instanced, the size parameter will be `0` and the generation terminates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that it's not possible to do what you need. The compiler has to deduce the types for the `Entries` parameter pack. However, the braced initializers that you want to pass in have no type. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), Notes section:

> A braced-init-list is not an expression and therefore has no type, e.g. `decltype({1,2})` is ill-formed. Having no type implies that template type deduction cannot deduce a type that matches a braced-init-list, so given the declaration `template<class T> void f(T);` the expression `f({1,2,3})` is ill-formed.

That's why gcc (according to [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/34n3d)) says that `Entries = {}`:

> 63:1: error: too many arguments to function 'constexpr Map create_const_map(Entries&& ...) [with K = int; V = int; Entries = {}]'

I guess if you want a more concise way to initialize your Map, you'd need to make a short-hand notation for the `std::make_pair`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not easily possible because as @Rostislav says, if the argument is a braces init list, the compiler cannot deduce a type for it.

I worked it around by manually creating a sufficiently large number of overloaded functions. In the following, the overloads are the function call operators (`operator()`) and `create_map` is a variable template of that function object. You pass the number of overloads to create to `Overload`. My C++ is rough, so perhaps this is not ideal, but it seems to work.

```
template<typename D, int N, typename ...E>
struct OverloadImpl;

template<typename D, int N, typename E, typename ...Es>
struct OverloadImpl<D, N, E, Es...> : OverloadImpl<D, N-1, E, E, Es...> {
    decltype(auto) operator()(const E& e, const Es&... es) {
       return static_cast<D&>(*this).exec(e, es...);
    }
    using OverloadImpl<D, N-1, E, E, Es...>::operator();
};

template<typename D, typename E, typename ...Es>
struct OverloadImpl<D, 0, E, Es...> { 
    decltype(auto) operator()() { 
       return static_cast<D&>(*this).exec();   
    }    
};

template<typename D, typename E, int N>
struct Overload : OverloadImpl<D, N, E>
{ };
```

To apply the above to your case, you can derive from `Overload` and provide an `exec` function.

```
template<typename K, typename V, int C>
struct M {
   template<typename ...T>
   M(T&&...) { }
};

template<typename K, typename V>
struct Entry {
   Entry(K, V) { }    
};

template<typename K, typename V>
struct CreateMapImpl : Overload<CreateMapImpl<K, V>, Entry<K, V>, 10> {
    template<typename ...T>
    M<K, V, sizeof...(T)> exec(const T&... t) {
       return { t... };   
    }
};

template<typename K, typename V>
CreateMapImpl<K, V> create_map{};

int main() {
   create_map<int, std::string>({1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, {3, "three"});   
}
```

Comment: "*my C++ is rough*" looks excellent to me -- what are you talking about?

Comment: Well, I guess there's very few "impossible" things in C++. Nice one :)